# Images in ViewPager don't fill the screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am receiving a set of URL images from API to show as slider so I am using viewpager to do my job and when I am trying to set Images in viewpager to fill screen according to imagesize this doesn't happen at all.

[image]

All the red line is huge spacing.. I am not sure why this there?

I am trying do the following in XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/pagerIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchlayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noData"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/nointernet"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/myviewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/progressContainer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                <com.ylg.librarys.ProgressWheel xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/progress_wheel"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:matProg_barColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/pagerLayoutIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pagerIndicator"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:fillColor="@color/orangeText"
                app:pageColor="@color/whitetext"
                app:strokeColor="@color/orangeText" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

PageAdapter looks like this:

```
@Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
        {
            progressContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            wheel_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            noData = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.noData);
            noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(bannerItems.get(position).getbannerImage(), 0, imageView);

            LayoutParams imageParams = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            layout.addView(imageView);

            final int page = position;
            layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
                            "Page " + page + " clicked", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }});

            container.addView(layout);

            return layout;
        }
```

Strangely If I don't give the height for the relativeLayout in which viewpager is sitting I don't see the image at all. that is If I set:

```
       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/pagerIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchlayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

I only get PageIndicator. Above ViewPager with image is not shown at all.

[image]

Not sure why this happening? How do I set the image match_parent so that it shows full without any gap?

Comment: maybe your image have gap. please check your image

Comment: @Phan Văn Linh : whole point is that 
I don't want to give size to my viewpager (which I have given in relative Layout) I want make match_parent and If I do I just get the pageIndicator and nothing else. Like shown in the screenshot in my question!

Comment: you see the the space around image is gray, do you know where gray color come from?

Comment: does your activity root have  padding set? it sets up by default

Comment: Yep. That is just a shaddow effect in the image. That is not the point. Is that it is not filling the screen. I have different image in the slider without the shadow effect.

Comment: @subhash: I have not set any padding. The code the I have added in this question exactly what I have.

Comment: @subhash: If I change 200dp to match_parent I don't see the image at all. I only see the PageIndicator that is all 6 dots.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh:  I have changed the screenshot. Now you should get an idea of what I am looking at..

Answer (score 4):

Try setting imageView's `ScaleType` .
For Example,

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

try also other ScaleTypes,

1. `ScaleType.CENTER`
2. `ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE`
3. `ScaleType.FIT_CENTER`

Hope this work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `instantiateItem` method

`imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);`

This will fill the whole screen with image removing whitespaces.

You can also try other methods

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

Answer (score 0):

There can't be fulfill your need.if a view pager contains an imageview, it needs a fixed height and width to imageview.you can set the scaletype as `fitStart` or `fitEnd` to make the gap before the image or after the image.it will solve a little gap problem.

Thank you.